# Infection of urinary tract if the pH of urine is made alkaline

Tags: pharmacology, pharmacokinetics

It is very well known that drugs like phenobarbiton,morphine are unionized, lipid soluble.So,in case if there is toxicity due to these drugs,the only way to save the patient is make the pH of urine alkaline and thus facilitating its excretion.But,the normal pH of the urine is acidic which protects the person from various urinary tract infections,if the pH is made alkaline is there a increased for the patient to have urinary tract infections?

Answer (score 2):

There is a huge misconception here.  Morphine overdose is treated with Narcan (naloxone).  Phenobarbiton overdose is treated with artificial respiration (in extreme cases), blood pressure medication, and management of low heart rate.  The concept of lowering the pH of the urine to increase a drug excretion is (to my knowledge) never used in emergency settings.  Dialysis, which filters the blood, would be used to 'clean' the blood of toxins.  Think about it.  Time is life, and changing the composition of your fluids would take a lifetime compared to the implemented measures in emergency rooms.  You body has an extremely sensitive acid-base balance.  You do **not** want to try to increase or decrease the pH of your bodily fluids.